# Using ACS ACR1222L NFC Reader with RPi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, rfid, pcsc

I'm trying to get the ACR1222L NFC reader to work with the RPi. I have already tested the reader successfully on a Windows system. Under Raspberry Pi OS pcsc_scan detects the NFC tag,but trying to connect to the card delivers "Card is unresponsive".

Card:
ISO 14443-3A
NXP - Mifare Classic 1k

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is and why the Card is "unresponsive" under Raspberry Pi OS?

pcsc_scan delivers:

```
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
0: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 00
1: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 01
2: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 02
3: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 03

Wed Jun 14 12:19:10 2023
 Reader 0: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 00
  Event number: 1
  Card state: Card inserted,
  ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A

ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 8F, Y(1): 1000, K: 15 (historical bytes)
  TD(1) = 80 --> Y(i+1) = 1000, Protocol T = 0
-----
  TD(2) = 01 --> Y(i+1) = 0000, Protocol T = 1
-----
+ Historical bytes: 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00
  Category indicator byte: 80 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 4, len: F (initial access data)
      Initial access data: 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00
+ TCK = 6A (correct checksum)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 .. 00 01 00 00 00 00 ..
        MIFARE Classic 1K (as per PCSC std part3)
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 .. .. 00 00 00 00 ..
        RFID - ISO 14443 Type A Part 3 (as per PCSC std part3)
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
        NXP/Philips MIFARE Classic 1K (as per PCSC std part3)
        http://www.nxp.com/#/pip/pip=[pfp=41863]|pp=[t=pfp,i=41863]
        Oyster card - Transport for London (first-gen)
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyster_card
        ACOS5/1k Mirfare
        vivotech ViVOcard Contactless Test Card
        Bangkok BTS Sky SmartPass
        Mifare Classic 1K (block 0 re-writeable)
        Electic vehicle charging card of the German Telekom, acting as EMSP GetCharge
        Electic vehicle charging card of the EMSP Stadtwerke Muenchen (SWM), ladenetz.de, Germany
        Electic vehicle charging card of the EMSP EinfachStromLaden of Maingau-Energie, Germany
        Scouter carsharing customer card in Germany
        https://scouter.de/
 Reader 1: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 01
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card,
 Reader 2: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 02
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card,
 Reader 3: ACS ACR Card Reader 00 03
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card inserted, Unresponsive card,
```

scriptor delivers:

```
No reader given: using ACS ACR Card Reader 00 00
Can't allocate Chipcard::PCSC::Card object: Card is unresponsive.
```

connect() from pyscard delivers:

```
 raise CardConnectionException(
smartcard.Exceptions.CardConnectionException: Unable to connect with protoco                                                                                 l: T0 or T1. Card is unresponsive.
```